# data tables to pass bulk values in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to pass bulk values to my stored procedure using a data table as follows:

```
 var idlist = new DataTable();
        idlist.Columns.Add("sid", typeof(int));
        idlist.Columns.Add("suid", typeof(int));
        idlist.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 1});
        idlist.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 2});
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SID", Convert.ToString(idlist)));
```

In SQL Server the stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SUBNETTEMP]
(
@SID as IDLISTS READONLY
 )

AS
BEGIN

Create table [tempIDTable] (sid int, suid int)

Insert into [tempIDTable]

select * from @SID

END
```

`IDLISTS` is defined as table type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE IDLISTS AS TABLE (
SID int, SUID int )
go
```

After running the program I am not sure why my stored procedure does not create `temIDTable`. I am not sure whether the stored procedure executed successfully or not? Can anyone pls help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why the parameters must be a table? Could you change the parameters to 2 separate int fields instead of a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code, you must specify the sqlDBType to use a table-value parameter.

So try this:

```
SqlParameter myParam = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SID", idlist));
myParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) for more info and examples.

Comment: also change : Convert.ToString(idlist) to just : idlist

Comment: @Moe Sisko, thanks for catching that. I changed code to remove the Convert.